# How can I calculate the exposure of future option?

Tags: options, futures

1. quantity * delta * index
2. quantity * delta * (index - strike)
3. quantity * delta * min(index - strike, 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example calculation of delta relative to index (share price) and a calculation of option price exposure relative to share price.

The delta calculation can also be found here: [Delta for European options](http://www.quantitative-finance-by-examples.com/option-delta.html)

Note, If using Excel, `Log` should be implemented using `LN` (natural log) and `CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]` can be implemented using `NORMSDIST(x)`.

[image]

[image]

***Calculation check:***

With the example inputs, for share price `s = 50` the respective results for the price of a call and a put should be:

```
c = 3.29154
p = 2.67043
```